# Angular: Update template without ngModel

Tags: angular

I'm trying to achieve multi-select functionality and display the selected items using checkoxes.
**HTML**

```
<div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" (click)="showCheckboxes()">
         <select>
             <option>{{selectedBaseLicences}}</option>
         </select>
    <div class="overSelect"></div>
 </div>
<div id="checkboxes">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let base of baseLicences">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" (click)="myFunction(base)">
            <span class="checkbox__input"></span>
            <span class="checkbox__label">{{base}}</span>
         </label>
    </ng-container>
 </div>
```

**TS**

```
public selectedBaseLicences: string[] = [];

public showCheckboxes() {
        let checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
        if (!this.expanded) {
          checkboxes.style.display = "block";
          this.expanded = true;
        } else {
          checkboxes.style.display = "none";
          this.expanded = false;
        }
      }

    public myFunction(selectedBase) {
        this.selectedBaseLicences.push(selectedBase)
    }
```

I'm trying to display the checked base in Select as an array but template is not getting updated after this.selectedBaseLicences.push(selectedBase) operation. How to update the template in this case?

Answer (score 2):

What the `push` method of Array  really does is append another object to the existing array (with no reference change) and Angular change detection only checks objects identity.

What you can do is to copy the array after each update using **[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** method which returns a new array.

```
 public myFunction(selectedBase) {
        this.selectedBaseLicences.push(selectedBase);
       this.selectedBaseLicences= this.selectedBaseLicences.slice()
    }
```

or you could use **[`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**

```
 public myFunction(selectedBase) {
                this.selectedBaseLicences.push(selectedBase);
               this.selectedBaseLicences= [...this.selectedBaseLicences]
            }
```